# How can I control how quickly a character levels up in an RPG?

Tags: game-design, rpg, mathematics

I am working on an RPG and I've mostly followed formulas from the *Dragon Quest* series and they've all been fairly simple. (For example, `dmg = (Attack/2 - Defense/4)`, where `Attack` is `Weapon Power+STR`.)

**Experience points** are more complicated though. I want one of the characters to level more slowly compared to the others. I'm not comfortable with the maths, but how would I go about creating a suitable exponential growth formula that is slow from let's say levels 1 through 40 and then speeds up to 99?

Comment: There are a few other questions tagged with [tag:experience] too. Are those helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can always set fixed values of XP for killing monsters/doing quests/interactions/crafting, so that e.g. after reaching 40 level or so player is capable of handling packs of monsters that give him much XP, so that he will level up quickly, or maybe set quests that give you much XP. Also, test your setup, and if you feel like player will be leveling up too slowly, you can always change these.